# How to access the markdown files stored in the second repository in the Astro framework

Tags: javascript, html, github-api, readme, astrojs

How to access the markdown files stored in the second repository in the Astro framework.

I am working on a website that is built using the Astro framework. Below is the function `glob` which returns an array of posts that are live at `.src/pages/post/*.md` . I want to know, how I can view the posts written in another public repository stored in `.md` file.

```js
const posts = await Astro.glob('../pages/post/*.md'); // returns an array of posts that live at ./src/pages/post/*.md
```

```html
<div>
{posts.slice(0, 3).map((post) => (
  <article>
    <h2>{post.frontmatter.title}</h2>
    <p>{post.frontmatter.description}</p>
    <a href={post.url}>Read more</a>
  </article>
))}
</div>
```